# Not catching internet explorer traffic on google analytics

Tags: internet-explorer, google-analytics

I want to redo a site using flexbox but I need to see how many users use internet explorer to see how many would be effected if i don't spend much time with modernizr if there aren't many users on IE 10 and before. So I jump on his website and look at traffic for the past 6 months and to my astonishment not a SINGLE IE user... that is awesome! Too awesome... so I jump on IE myself and give it a day and sure enough, still no IE traffic.

Here is the site:
http://greatplainslandscapes.com/

I get a couple errors on console (only in IE) saying how doctype is declared a few times , but not sure what would be causing IE not to work with Google Analytics. I am getting rid of my old site so I would rather not spend TOO much time getting it to work.

Comment: You should consider upgrading to use analytics.js instead of the older ga.js code. If you do, you can use the [debugger](https://devsite.googleplex.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging) to help you solve problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using classic version of google analytics which is outdate and its recommended to move to universal
but this still doesn't explain why IE users are not coming in GA

You can use the debugger for IE to check if any requests are being sent to google analytics.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingTroubleshooting

Also when you come from IE do you see yourself in GA real-time report. can you check if there are any filters applied that are excluding IE users.

Hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML.